# React Paginate Second Instance on same page does not re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-paginate for pagination and I have two instances on the same page. One on top and one on the bottom, when new prop is received only top one is re-rendered. Below is the code, I have checked the different lifecycle methods on the component if it receives new props and render method is called, all seems to be working but in the page only top pagination works meaning if I click on Page 2, second instance should also change to Page 2 because it received a new value for selected page. Any thoughts?

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

    export default class Pager extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
      }

      render() {

        return (
          <div className={`pager ${this.props.position}`}>
            <ReactPaginate 
              previousLabel={'Prev'}
              nextLabel = {'Next'}
              breakLabel = {<a href="">...</a>}
              breakClassName = {"break-me"}
              pageCount = {this.props.totalPages}
              marginPagesDisplayed ={1}
              pageRangeDisplayed={2}
              onPageChange = {this.props.onPageNumberClick}
              containerClassName = {"page-links-container"}
              pageLinkClassName = {"pg-links"}
              activeClassName = {"active"} 
              previousClassName = {"prev-pg-lnk"}
              nextClassName = {"next-pg-lnk"}
              disabledClassName = {"disabled"}
              initialPage = {parseInt(this.props.selectedPage) -1}
              />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use `forcePage` prop to sync the both paginations.

So once a page is changed, in `onPageChange` callback you update the state of a wrapper component (that holds both pagination components) with the updated page number. To make both paginations work in sync - you have to set `forcePage` to be equal to the wrapper's state `selected` page numer.

I've tested it locally with the [plugin's official demo](https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate/tree/master/demo). Here is the example code (focus on `render` and `handlePageClick` methods):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import $ from 'jquery';

window.React = React;


export class CommentList extends Component {
  render() {
    let commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment, index) {
      return (
        <div key={index}>{comment.comment}</div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div id="project-comments" className="commentList">
        <ul>
          {commentNodes}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      offset: 0,
      selected: null
    }
  }

  loadCommentsFromServer() {
    $.ajax({
      url      : this.props.url,
      data     : {limit: this.props.perPage, offset: this.state.offset},
      dataType : 'json',
      type     : 'GET',

      success: data => {
        this.setState({data: data.comments, pageCount: Math.ceil(data.meta.total_count / data.meta.limit)});
      },

      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
  }

  handlePageClick = (data) => {
    let selected = data.selected;
    let offset = Math.ceil(selected * this.props.perPage);

    this.setState({offset: offset, selected}, () => {
      this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <ReactPaginate previousLabel={"previous"}
                       nextLabel={"next"}
                       breakLabel={<a href="">...</a>}
                       breakClassName={"break-me"}
                       pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
                       marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                       pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                       onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
                       containerClassName={"pagination"}
                       subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                       activeClassName={"active"}
                       forcePage={this.state.selected} />

        <ReactPaginate previousLabel={"previous"}
                       nextLabel={"next"}
                       breakLabel={<a href="">...</a>}
                       breakClassName={"break-me"}
                       pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
                       marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                       pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                       onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
                       containerClassName={"pagination"}
                       subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                       activeClassName={"active"}
                       forcePage={this.state.selected} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App url={'http://localhost:3000/comments'}
       author={'adele'}
       perPage={10} />,
  document.getElementById('react-paginate')
);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was going to update the answer. I did figure this out after some troubleshooting, I will accept your answer.

Thank you!

Comment: In my case, both pagination controls stop showing the active page, and next/prev buttons stop working, when I use `forcePage`. 

Wonder if anyone else is also encountering this.

Comment: It is still work `forcePage={currentPageNumber-1}` I just implement like this

Comment: When I use forcePage, the active class is not being set to the corresponding page 'li' tag. is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use key prop in paginate component so two instance will work without any problem.

Ex.

> `<ReactPaginate     key="paginate1"    forcePage={...} />`
>
> `<ReactPaginate     key="paginate2"    forcePage={...} />`